# How to use validates_associated for join table in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an association between the two tables with a join table like this:

```
class Patient
  has_and_belongs_to_many :doctors
end

class Doctor
  has_and_belongs_to_many :patients
end

# join table for patients_doctors
class CreatePatientDoctors < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :patients_doctors, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :patient, :null => false
      t.references :doctor, :null => false
    end
    add_index :patients_doctors, [:patient_id, :doctor_id]
  end
end
```

I want a condition such that `a patient should consult a doctor` only once. (This is just for example as i cant share my client's code here)

As of now when i try to save a `duplicate entry` it displays the `database level constraint error` at the log like this:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_uniqueness"
DETAIL:  Key (patient_id, doctor_id)=(16, 1) already exists.
```

I want to use `validation` to have better control and usability factor.

I tried to use the `validates_associated` for the `Doctor` class

```
  # in patient class
  validates :doctors, uniqueness: true
  validates_associated :doctors
```

But still i'm getting the same `database constraint error`. Please suggest me where i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You need to validate in the PatientDoctor model that the combination of patient_id and doctor_id is unique. You can do this using scope, which you can list attributes to limit the uniqueness check:

```
validates :patient_id, uniqueness: { scope: :doctor_id }
```

validates_associated ensures that associated records are valid. It doesn't check for the uniqueness of the association.

Comment: I don't have PatientDoctor model as association is HABTM

Comment: Actually the combination of `[patient_id , doctor_id]` should be unique.

Comment: I guess you should change the association to `has_many through` association.